# Count observatons by group with dplyr

Tags: dplyr

Trying this again, with less words to hopefully get some helpful feedback.

I am manipulating the following code with dplyr and would like to estimate an empirical logit transform for each `person`, `item`, and `node` combination. The number of observations for the logit transform is the `time` variable.

Note that Empirical logit is equal to:
[image: $$ EL = Prob_i $$]

```
data.el <- structure(list(trial = c(6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7), person = c(2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2), time = c(40, 60, 40, 60, 40, 60), node = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), yy = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

The problem with my code block is that is counting all of the rows when I run
`mutate(n_yy = n())`. In the printed outcome EL2 we can see that N_yy is 2 for all items; however, I ultimate want the count in yy to reflect to total number of 1's observed for node 3, node 2, and node 1 respectively.  Therefore, the desired output is in the table below.

| time | yy | node | n_yy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 60 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 40 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 60 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 40 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 60 | 0 | 3 | 0 |

This code creates the unintended output.

```
library(dplyr)
EL2 = data.el %>%
  count(trial, time, yy, node, person) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  mutate(n_obs = n()) %>%
  #ungroup() %>%
  group_by(node) %>%
  mutate(n_yy = n()) %>%
  mutate(prop_yy = n_yy/n_obs)
```

The below code is my desired dataframe and will work fine if the above code runs as intended

```
Empirical.Logit = data.frame(
  trial = EL2$trial,
  time = EL2$time,
  node = EL2$node,
  empirical.logit = (EL2$prop_yy + 0.5) / (EL2$n_obs - EL2$n_yy) + 0.5
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To following produces your expected output:

```r
data.el %>%
  group_by(node) %>%
  mutate(n_yy = sum(yy)) %>%
  select(time, yy, node, n_yy)
```

If `yy` is not just a binary variable, then I would suggest:

```r
data.el %>%
  group_by(node) %>%
  mutate(n_yy = sum(ifelse(yy != 0, 1, 0))) %>% # make binary
  select(time, yy, node, n_yy)
```

Comment: The code for this works perfect. For clarification. After you use group_by() can you use the sum, count, summarize etc on everything that was grouped? When I added extra participants I found that I needed to ```group_by(node, trial, and participant)``` to make the code functional for the larger data set.  Thanks for your help, simon!

Comment: Yes, you you can group by multiple columns. E.g.: `group_by(col1, col2, col3)`. Yes you can summarise multiple things at once. E.g.: `summarise(n_yy = sum(yy), num_obs = n(), min_node = min(node))`.